# Xcode IDE Showing Error: "Control Reaches End Of Non-Void Function"

Tags: c, function-call

I am trying to add two numbers using functions in Xcode but I am getting this error:

> "Control Reaches End Of Non-Void Function"

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int add();
}
int add()
{
    int a,b,c;
    printf("Enter The Two Values12");
    scanf("%d%d", &a,&b);
    c=a+b;
    printf("The Sum is = %d", c);
}
```

Comment: You have more problem than you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

The warning message is very clear, you're not returning a value, as *promised*.

The `add()` function returns an `int`, but in your code, there is no `return` statement altogether. You need to return a value, as the return type you define is `int`.

Quoting `C11`, chapter 6.9.1/P12

> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

So your compiler is trying to warn you of possible pitfall.

---

That said

- You need to forward declare your function outside `main()`.
- You should call the `add()` function from `main()`, something like

  ```
  int main()
  {
      add();
  }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

I dont know much of the technical but there is no need to create add function and also in 6th line you missed a semicolon. Omit 3,4,5 and 6 line and at the end add *return 0*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    printf("Enter The Two Values1 & 2 \n");
    scanf("%d%d", &a,&b);
    c=a+b;
    printf("The Sum is = %d", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. -- Unfortunately, your answer does not explain the error the OP got. The other answer did this already in a good way.